# ZF2 unable to select all rows in tablegateway method

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I m just new to ZF2 and using the following function.

```
public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }
```

When I use print_r($resultSet) it is showing the following in the result instead of all rows in table, which is i am expecting. can u tell why it is not showing all rows.

```
Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet Object
(
    [allowedReturnTypes:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => arrayobject
            [1] => array
        )

    [arrayObjectPrototype:protected] => Users\Model\User Object
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => 
            [email] => 
            [password] => 
        )

    [returnType:protected] => arrayobject
    [buffer:protected] => 
    [count:protected] => 3
    [dataSource:protected] => Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object
        (
            [statementMode:protected] => forward
            [resource:protected] => PDOStatement Object
                (
                    [queryString] => SELECT `user`.* FROM `user`
                )

            [options:protected] => 
            [currentComplete:protected] => 
            [currentData:protected] => 
            [position:protected] => -1
            [generatedValue:protected] => 0enter code here
            [rowCount:protected] => 3
        )

    [fieldCount:protected] => 4
    [position:protected] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data source is a PDO result set. You will see the results when you start iterating the object.

If you dump the contents of:

```
$resultSet->count();
```

You'll see that it's returned three rows.

Iterate as follows:

```
foreach ($resultSet as $result) {
    echo $result->id;
    echo $result->name;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: how to iterate that, i have did the following.<?php 
$users = $this->users;

foreach($users as $userkey->$value){ ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $value;  ?></td>
    <td><?php ?></td>
    <td><?php ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example of iterating the result set.

Comment: can you explain this? $resultSet is returned from the model, so if you have in your controller $albums = $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(), print_r($albums) will output something like the OP posted.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but $albums should be iterable. In your case, it sounds like $resultSet is the same as $albums.